# Why cant I hard code in the values that are in the range of the for statement?

Tags: python

I do not understand how the following code works in the function:

```
for i in range(len(s)-len(sub)+1):
    if sub == s[i:i+len(sub)]:
```

Why cant I just pass `range(4)` for it to work?

write a function that takes two string parameters called 'sub' and 's' and returns the number of times sub occurs as a contiguous substring of s

```
s= "nickdick"
sub= "ick"


def function(sub,s):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s)-len(sub)+1):
        if sub == s[i:i+len(sub)]:
            count +=1
    print(count)
    return count
```

Comment: Why would you hardcode the length of the string passed to a function? You want it to use the length of the actual string! BTW, `s.count(sub)` does the job - if you want to be smart, you hand in this as an alternative solution for your homework: `def function(sub, s): return s.count(sub)`

Comment: Well, 4 isn't the right value in your example:  the length of `s` is 8, and the length of `sub` is 3, so `len(s)-len(sub)+1` is 6.  If you used `range(6)` it'd work for these two strings, but it wouldn't work correctly for strings of different lengths.

Comment: Imagine you put a hardcoded number in there (like 4), then called the function with the strings "asdfasdfasdfasdf" and "asdfa". What would happen then?

Answer (score 3):

You can use 4 and it would be valid code if `len(s)-len(sub)+1` happened to be 4 for those strings. However, the purpose of writing it using `len` is so that if you decide to change `s` or `sub`, the code still functions and you don't have to go through and manually change the "magic constant" 4.